# Is my understanding of this level shifter correct

Tags: current, current-limiting, level-shifting

I am considering using this TI LSF0102 level shifter in my circuit - but would like to understand, based upon [its datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lsf0102.pdf), if I have my understanding correct.

It says it has a 100mA current rating, is that a limit on each of the 2 channels? Or total combined limit?

Comment: Can you quote the area you refer to?

Answer (score 1):

The only reference to "100mA" that I find in the datasheet has to do with electrostatic discharge limits.

I think you need to look at the section titled "Recommended Operating Conditions" on page 5:

[image]

"Pass transistor current" is what you are looking for.   It says 64mA.  So, you are allowed 64mA through each translator.

You really shouldn't get that close to 64mA.

Consider a typical translator with pullups to 5V on one side and 3.3V on the other side.  If you use 100 ohm pull up resistors, you will get 50mA through the translator when the 3.3V side pulls low.  Any normal pull ups (10k to 100k) will have much lower current, so you shouldn't end up in a situation where you hit the maximum current.

What you do have to watch out for is if one (either side) is actively driving a high signal while the other side is pulling a low signal.  Those conditions might get you more current through the translator than allowed - and make your driving circuit unhappy as well.

The datasheet goes into some detail about what to do if you have active drive signals rather than open signals to deal with.

Comment: Hi JRE, I don't think I completely follow. If I am powering something on the 5v side of the shifter, which is expecting to draw , say 100mA isn't that going to pull that through one of the translaters of the level shifter?

Comment: Level shifters are made for matching voltages for digital signal levels, not converting power for devices.

Comment: Ah. So is there an equivalent for powering levels of devices? If so do you know its name>

Comment: What you are looking for is called a voltage regulator.  Put a somewhat higher voltage in on one side, get a specific lower voltage out on the other side.

Comment: Also,the level translator requires you to already have both voltages available - the high and the low.